# WPF - Why are my controls getting cut off during runtime?

Tags: wpf

Looking at my window at design time shows that all the controls fit inside:

[image: Design time, controls appearing normnal.]

When I run the application the form looks like this in runtime:
[image: Runtime, controls do not fit.]

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_App.BrowseDirectory"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LM_Config_Manager"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Browse Directory" Height="114" Width="420" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid >
        <TextBox x:Name="tbPath" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,25,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329"/>
        <Button x:Name="bBrowse" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="344,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" Click="bBrowse_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="bOK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsDefault="True" Click="bOK_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="bCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsCancel="True" Click="bCancel_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window looks like its shrinking during runtime...

What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You've specified a specific Height and Width in your Window attributes. A better option might be to remove those and add

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

Looking at your runtime Window, it looks like you have a specific theme or style applied to the window which isn't applied design-time, which is why the two look different.

Comment: I didn't apply any theme.  I added a new WPF Window, added the controls and hit start.

Answer (score 0):

The designer apparentl uses another window frame but since it is only the runtime appearance that matters you could specify a `Margin` of the root `Grid` in your XAML markup:

```
<Grid Margin="16">
    <TextBox x:Name="tbPath" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,25,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329"/>
    <Button x:Name="bBrowse" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="344,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" Click="bBrowse_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="bOK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsDefault="True" Click="bOK_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="bCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsCancel="True" Click="bCancel_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's silly that the design and runtime layouts don't match.  Is there a way that I can make them match?

Comment: Are you using a custom window template? Then you need to make sure that this template also gets applied at runtime. Othwerise, no, I don't think so.

Comment: No I didn't apply anything custom.  I added the new wpf window to the project, added the controls and hit start.

Comment: No then. Because, as you see, the window frame looks different in the Visual Studo designer. I rarely use the designer at all. You can disable it if you want: http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the window minimum width and minimum height to the width and height in the designer. You can do that by setting margins but it is usually too much hassle. Make sure you do not go over standard windows monitor size 1920 x 1080 (1080p) or for very old windows, 1024x768.In other words, make the window as small as you can, ensuring it is still usable.